# How to browse multiples arrays JSON

Tags: json, handlebars.js

In my web page, I have a list group of items on the left side and should've some fields on the right side. With this JSON, how can I only browse fields.field array to print my input fields on the right side? I'm using Handlebars.JS

```js
{
 "refs": {
  "ref": [{
   "alias": "alias1",
   "fields": {
    "field": [{
     "libelle": "Libelle",
     "name": "ref_libelle",
     "type": "text",
     "value": "value"
    }, {
     "libelle": "Alias",
     "name": "ref_alias",
     "type": "text",
     "value": "value2"
    }]
   }
  }]
 }
}
```

Comment: Where is your template code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I got it right, but maybe using paths

```js
var data = {
  "refs": {
    "ref": [
     {
        "alias": "alias1",
        "fields": {
          "field": [
            {
              "libelle": "Libelle",
              "name": "ref_libelle",
              "type": "text",
              "value": "value"
            }, {
              "libelle": "Alias",
              "name": "ref_alias",
              "type": "text",
              "value": "value2"
            }
          ]
        }
     }
    ]
  }
};

var source = $("#entry-template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var html = template(data);
$('#foo').html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.6/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#each refs.ref}}
   {{#each fields.field}}
     <div>{{libelle}}</div>
    {{/each}}
  {{/each}}
</script>

<div id="foo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`var name1= refs.ref[0].fields.field[0].name;
var val1 = refs.ref[0].fields.field[0].value;`

`refs.ref[0].fields.field[1].name;`
`refs.ref[0].fields.field[1].value;`

If you don't know the key value means, just get the key values of JSON and search with key value.

Comment: I'm using Handlebars.JS syntax, I tried something like :      {{#each refs.ref}}
      {{#alias}}
       {{#each ../fields.field}}
           <label class="control-label col-lg-2"> {{name}}
            </label>
      
    {{/each}}
   {{/alias}}
  {{/each}} . But it prints me too much fields coz I was browsing Refs array and fields array and I wanna got only fields array to print his contents.